# NativeCrypto errors Amazon Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have the following logcat from a user who is experiencing a force close while trying to download data from AWS.  Does anyone know what the NativeCrypto errors are?

> I/com.amazonaws.request( 3553): Sending Request: POST https://sdb.amazonaws.com / Parameters: (ConsistentRead: true, Action: GetAttributes, SignatureMethod: HmacSHA256, ItemName: XXXX, DomainName: YYYY, AWSAccessKeyId: ZZZZ, SignatureVersion: 2, Version: 2009-04-15, Signature: WWWWWWW, Timestamp: 2012-02-09T16:23:02.443Z, )

---

> D/NativeCrypto( 3553): returned from sslSelect() with result 0, error code 2

---

> D/NativeCrypto( 3553): returned from sslSelect() with result 1, error code 2

---

> I/com.amazonaws.request( 3553): Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: d039ba97-205d-356b-5cf3-2616d0778e53

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the exact Android version of the device in question. The SSL connection is failing for some reason, not clear why. Check if it fails every time or only under certain conditions. If it is an older Android version and it fails every time, it might not have the CA certificates Amazon SDB is using installed.

Comment: Android 2.3 is what the guy is using.